# Flattening a nested list with labels, preserving the labels, without dynamic allocation

Tags: python

I have data like this:

```
lst = [('label1', [1.1, 1.2, ...]), 
       ('label2', [2.1, 2.2, ...]), 
       ('label3', 3.), ... ]
```

Where some tuples have a nested list of elements, and some are a single element (where the single element is not iterable).  I'd like to flatten the data to:

```
newlst = [('label1', 1.1), ('label1', 1.2), ... ('label3', 3.) ...]
```

I can simply do something like:

```
newlst = []
for tup in lst:
    try:
        newlst.extend([(tup[0], y) for y in tup[1]])
    except TypeError:
        newlst.append(tup)
```

But this dynamically allocates newlst.  I could also pass through lst once, count up all the elements, make newlst = [None] * N_elements, then pass through again and assign values, but this feels clunky.  Is there a better way to avoid dynamic allocation of newlst?

Comment: Why do you care whether the list is reallocated during this process?

Comment: IMHO there's not much point worrying about this: CPython's `list` is fairly clever at reallocating its data storage space. I suggest you take a look at the [listobject.c source code on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c). Even if you don't read C you should be able to get the general idea of its strategy just from the code comments.

Comment: My motives are combined performance and curiosity.  Agreed Python's list is pretty clever compared to others, but I've also written Python code in the past that was very recursively appending to a list and it took hours versus seconds (or maybe minutes?) once I pre-allocated.

Comment: Fair enough. If you're doing lots of small appends / extends it certainly can be faster to pre-allocate; OTOH, scanning to determine the necessary size could take a sizeable chunk of time too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list comprehension over `lst`

```
newlst = [(label, el) for label, sublst in lst 
                      for el in (sublst if hasattr(sublst, "__iter__") else [sublst])]
```

Comment: full disclosure I have no idea if this allocates memory for the whole block at once or builds it piecemeal like you're trying to avoid, but that sort of thinking strongly smacks of premature optimization so I advise to avoid worrying about it.

Comment: That will still use a growing allocation.  Not that that's really a bad thing in general, but the question was trying to avoid it.

Comment: Apart, it doesn't solve the question, right?! Will throw a type error as well.

Comment: I would guess, or is `for i in 3.:` valid python?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest argh, you're certainly right. Hang on

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest fixed. That was dumb sorry :D

Comment: Thanks for formatting the answer as you did.  I tried a list comprehension originally but kept messing up the syntax with the if involved.  Regarding allocation for a list comprehension, I've always wondered if that was just effectively a series of appends or if it was something more clever (maybe a dict or a linked list that gets combined into a real list at the end?).  I always assumed list comprehensions were more clever than a series of appends, but never been sure...

Comment: @Andrew I don't know what the implementation is for list comprehensions, honestly. I would assume that under the hood it's doing little better than a series of appends, essentially because doing otherwise would force it to double its workload (iterate once to count, initialize to size N, iterate again to populate) and wouldn't provide *any* positive benefits whatsoever if you so much as append once to it.